# Adding multiple DropDownLists with a button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Using a combination of ASP.NET (with C#) and jQuery, I'm try to create `DropDownList`s with a button.  These `DropDownList`s will be populated with a SQL query.

The part I'm having difficulty with is adding more than one using just the button click.

If the user clicks the button 5 times, 5 more `DropDownList`s should be created and populated with the same data.  Ideally, each `DropDownList` is contained in a new row of a table, or organized in a similar fashion.

I do not want to do any SQL connections in JavaScript.  Any advice with this?

**Edit:**

I've tried using an `<asp:PlaceHolder>`, and then using that to add a `DropDownList`.  I could not figure out how to use this method and add more than one, though.:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>

protected void Add_Dropdownlist()
{
   DropDownList DropDownList1 = new DropDownList();
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DropDownList1);
}
```

I've tried using jQuery to copy the original `DropDownList`.  The problem I had, was that I couldn't figure out how to get the the original `DropDownList` from jQuery if it was an `<asp:DropDownList>`.  If I changed it to a `<select>` instead, I could not figure out how to populate it with SQL data from the ASP (server) side.

```
<select id="DropDownList1">
  <option value="-1"></option>
</select>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

function copy_Dropdownlist()
{
  newDropdownlist = jQuey.extend({}, DropDownList2);
}
```

In short, I've gone down several paths, but I don't think any of them are right.  I'm new to ASP.NET (google education) and I think the problems lies in linking the client side jQuery and the server side ASP.NET.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide something you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is in reference to your `<asp:PlaceHolder>` approach.  I'm actually going to use an `<asp:Panel>`, as it seems more appropriate here)

It looks like the problem you're running into is that the `DropDownList`s are not persisted across postbacks.  So, each time you create a new one and add it to your `PlaceHolder`, you still only end up with one.

To resolve this, you need to keep track of the ones you've already created.  In your `Page_Load`, you want to create a storage container for your `DropDownList`s (I use a `List<>` for this) and save it in the user's "`Session`".  Notice the `!Page.IsPostBack`; you only want to create this once (the first time the page loads, not each time you PostBack):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<DropDownList> DDLList = new List<DropDownList>();
        Session["DDLs"] = DDLList;
    }
}
```

Now when you click the button, you can

- Get the currently existing `DropDownList`s (if any) from your `Session` variable,
- Add the new one for this button click to that list
- Add all of your `DropDownList`s to the `Panel`,
- And save the updated list back to your `Session` variable.

Like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList newDropDown = new DropDownList();
    List<DropDownList> existingDropDowns = (List<DropDownList>)Session["DDLs"];
    existingDropDowns.Add(newDropDown);

    foreach (DropDownList dropdown in existingDropDowns)
    {
        Panel1.Controls.Add(dropdown);
    }

    Session["DDLs"] = existingDropDowns;
}
```

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but this should hopefully get you started.

Answer (score 0):

@jadarnel27

Thanks a lot for the help, it got me to where I needed to go.  I had to do a bit more work to handle the post back on selection change.  Here is what I ended up with.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
      List<DropDownList> DDLList = new List<DropDownList>();
      Session["DDLs"] = DDLList;
  }
  else
  {
    List<DropDownList> existingDropDowns = (List<DropDownList>)Session["DDLs"];
    //Add all existing DropDownLists to Panel
    foreach (DropDownList dropdown in existingDropDowns)
    {
      Panel1.Controls.Add(dropdown);
      dropdown.AutoPostBack=true;
      Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    }
    Session["DDLs"] = existingDropDowns;
  }
}

protected void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  List<DropDownList> existingDropDowns = (List<DropDownList>)Session["DDLs"];
  DropDownList newDropDown = new DropDownList();        
  newDropDown.ID = "DDL" + existingDropDowns.Count.ToString();
  //Bind DropDownList to SQL Table
  Populate_List("mySQLTable", newDropDown, "");
  existingDropDowns.Add(newDropDown);
  //Add only new DropDownList to Panel
  Panel1.Controls.Add(newDropDown);
  newDropDown.AutoPostBack=true;
  Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
  Session["DDLs"] = existingDropDowns;
}

protected void clickSubmit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<DropDownList> existingDropDowns = (List<DropDownList>)Session["DDLs"];
  foreach (DropDownList dropdown in existingDropDowns)
  {
      //Insert each DropDownList selected value into SQL Table
      ETS.Core.Db.Database.ExecuteNoLog("INSERT INTO myNewTable (id,text) VALUES ('" + dropdown.SelectedValue + "', '" + dropdown.SelectedItem  + "')");
  }
}
```

Thanks again.