# Why dynamically loaded controls are lost during postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, dynamic-controls

**Scenario 1:** I am loading one user control dynamically. From this dynamically loaded user control i am loading other user controls dynamically.

But during post back all the dynamically loaded controls are lost.

**Scenario 2:** I placed one user control in Page.aspx page. In this user control i am loading other user controls dynamically.

But in this scenario during post back controls are retained.

**Why controls are retained in Scenario 2 and why not in Scenario 1?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem in **Scenario 1** is -

If you load a control dynamically, you need to reload it back in Page_Init (or Page_Load) with same Id after post-back.

In order to reload it back, we normally keep Control's Id in **ViewState** to persist the post-back.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095699/296861) is an example.

Comment: But why in scenario 2 controls are retained. In this scenario also i am loading controls dynamically from user control,i am not loading dynamically loaded user controls again during postback.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I could not say what causes the issue. However, dynamically created control in general requires to reload them back on post-back.